# Google maps Street View with custom view

Tags: google-maps, gis, geography

I'm curious whether it's possible to use Google Maps Street View as a platform along with custom views.

To be more clear, I'd like to build a seating chart for a venue, where seats would have uniques views.  As the user scrolls around or clicks on different seats, they'd be taken around the venue, just like in a Street View on Google Maps.  Of course, I'd need to come up with the views myself.

Looking through the developer docs, my suspicion is that this isn't possible.  Am I wrong, or are there any other platforms which I can use to build this on top of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available in V3 of the Google Maps API. It's discussed in [this presentation](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/moving-beyond-markers-advanced-maps-api.html), given at Google I/O this year.